# Why do I get a timestamp from ObjectId Spring/Mongo-RestController and how to avoid?

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I started with Kotlin Spring and Spring Data MongoDB and tried to follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/techwasti/spring-boot-mongodb-rest-api-using-kotlin-47e49729bb21

I get everything up and running, but my Entity/document:

```
@Document(collection = "products")
data class Product(
    @Id
    val id: ObjectId = ObjectId.get(),
    val name: String,
    val identifier: String,
    val owners: List<String> = listOf()
) {}
```

is resulting to

```
[{
    "id": {
        "timestamp": 1678022555,
        "date": "2023-03-05T13:22:35.000+00:00"
    },
    "name": "Product A",
    "identifier": "prod-a",
    "owners": []
}]
```

althought I got from mongosh:

```
db.products.find();
[{
  _id: ObjectId("6404979bbaa085d5514f0d9d"),
  name: 'Product A',
  identifier: 'prod-a'
}]
```

The code to retrieve the items from the DB is:

```
@GetMapping
fun getProducts(): ResponseEntity<List<Product>> {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(productRepository.findAll());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongos uses non-standard JSON (called BSON): `_id: ObjectId("6404979bbaa085d5514f0d9d")`.  In Kotlin, I assume you are using Spring and its serializer is showing the `ObjectId` via its underlying two parts which are legal JSON.

To get a string, then one method is to use this annotation on the field:

```
Document(collection = "products")
data class Product(
    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using= ToStringSerializer::class)
    val id: ObjectId = ObjectId.get(),
...
```

to instruct the mapper to serialize in a different way.